# Cannot authenticate Postgresql on Rails DB and/or edit a VIM file

Tags: postgresql

Fairly new to Ruby on Rails and i'm trying to move from an SQLITE3 DB to Postgresql.

I have installed the gem etc and changed the database.yml file to include the new Postgresql details. I have also started the service and logged into the console to create a user etc.

However, when using the same details as in the database.yml and/or those created for users directly in the console; i get the following error:

psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "xxxx"

I have spent many hours trying to edit the pg_hba.conf file using VIM which has driven me to destruction! I have apparently created loads of swap files which I have no idea how to delete and have spent hours and hours simply trying to edit the file to (i think) change the authentication type.

What have I done wrong in the setup process to cause these errors and how can I rectify this?

Something must be fundamentally wrong as I am sure you can't need to edit this silly file every time you create a DB, SQLITE seemed so trouble free!

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you do actually have to set aside a little time to, you know, learn about a new system before trying to use it. Also I get the feeling you aren't actually that familiar with computers in general (or their terminology).

So - that's not a "vim file" - it's just a text file. Vim is a text editor, but you can use a different one if you prefer or don't know how to operate it.

That file (pg_hba.conf) in particular controls the default [authentication methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) the PostgreSQL server will use when you try to connect to it. All this is covered in the extensive official online documentation and presumably in whatever tutorial you are following.

Because you can connect to a PostgreSQL database remotely, and as multiple different users it needs to authenticate you when you connect. The pg_hba.conf file is a set of "first checks" that it can do without actually starting up a new database backend and querying user tables and the like.

Your error message states that you cannot connect using "peer" authentication. Your tutorial is probably recommending to change it to "md5" or some other password setup.

The pg_hba.conf file isn't editable by all users on the computer (that would make it pointless from a security point of view). So - you need to be either the "postgres" user (which is probably what PostgreSQL is running as, and is the user that owns that file) or "root" who can edit anything.

The "sudo" command lets you run other commands as a user other than yourself (if it has been set up correctly). So, the "sudo vim" is opening the vim editor as "root" which should let you edit the file.

If you manage to edit that file, you will want to restart the PostgreSQL service to get it to reload the settings.

As to why you have created a lot of swap files, I guess that is because you have either got stuck in vim and killed it off without exiting properly or because you have left several copies of it running. They are just files and can be deleted (if you have the appropriate permissions) like any other file.

I get the feeling that you are trying to jump several steps ahead of your current understanding. This may let you learn a lot quite quickly but can also lead to you wasting a lot of time because you don't know what mistakes you have made and also don't know how to correct them.

If you don't have an urgent need to learn how to administer a PostgreSQL server, then I suggest sticking with SQLite for the moment. Although PostgreSQL offers some outstanding features and is a very capable system it is inevitably a more complex system than a single library-driven file.

If you do want to press ahead, set aside a couple of hours first to make sure you understand the basics of how to operate and administrate your computer - set up users, groups, manage ownership of files and directories, change permissions on them, start stop and monitor services, know where your logfiles are and what goes to each one. Then at least you will only be learning about PostgreSQL and not a dozen other items too.

Comment: +1 Very much appreciate you taking the time to not only explain where I am going wrong but also give me some solid direction in terms of learning to walk before I can run. Like you say I have always found getting stuck into things a faster way to learn but completely agree that the underpinning understanding is often more valuable in the long term! Cheers Richard!

Comment: You'll look back eventually and wonder why you had any problems. Don't underestimate sqlite though - it's a very capable tool, and I say that having been a user and fan of Postgres for about 20 years now.